# Añadir texto al final de un archivo

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy haciendo varias cosas con **pandora**, y he creado un módulo KVM para comprobar si se está ejecutando o no una máquina virtual, el problema es que tengo que añadir a todos los agentes este texto al final del archivo pandora.cnf:

```
module_begin
module_name KVM_Status
module_type generic_proc
module_exec virsh -q list | grep "ejecutando" | wc -l
module_group Application
module_end
```

No he usado nunca **bash**, por lo que me es complicado ver como hacerlo, ¿me ayudáis?

Comment: ¿Cómo accedes a los agentes? Porque entiendo que deberías iterar sobre todos ellos y añadir el texto en cada uno de ellos

Comment: Accedo a través de SSH, conectándome 1 a 1, son aproximadamente 120 agentes

Comment: o sea que la cuestión sería coger un listado de servidores de algún lado, hacer ssh uno a uno y ejecutar el comando. ¿Tienes que poner usuario y contraseña en cada uno o tienes intercambio de cadenas hecho?

Comment: Tengo que ir poniendo usuario y contraseña uno a uno

Comment: Pues es fundamental que implementes el intercambio de claves --> http://badorius.com/?q=node/37 si no, esto será una locura. Te facilitará mucho la vida.

Comment: Perfecto, y una vez añadido el intercambio de claves que haría?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregarlo de la siguiente forma

```
echo 'module_begin' | sudo tee --append /ruta/absoluta/pandora.cnf
echo 'module_name KVM_Status' | sudo tee --append /ruta/absoluta/pandora.cnf
echo 'module_type generic_proc' | sudo tee --append /ruta/absoluta/pandora.cnf
echo 'module_exec virsh -q list | grep "ejecutando" | wc -l' | sudo tee --append /ruta/absoluta/pandora.cnf
echo 'module_group Application' | sudo tee --append /ruta/absoluta/pandora.cnf
echo 'module_end' | sudo tee --append /ruta/absoluta/pandora.cnf
```

Recuerda cambiar `/ruta/absoluta/` por la ruta donde esté ubicado tu archivo de configuración.

Comment: ¿por qué algo tan complicado? Con `echo "bla" >> fichero` ya basta.

Comment: Recientemente tuve que hacer algo parecido para una máquina de Vagrant y por alguna razón no me funcionó, de ahí que usara este método

Answer (score 0):

si quieres guardar al final de un archivo.txt lo que contiene un script.sh, entonces ejecuta en CLI:
cat script.sh >> archivo.txt

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).